# Regular expression length (0) or (7-50)

Tags: regex, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

The regex here is using `wp-rest-api` enpoints regex so what I have is

```
$routes['/dn/settings/update/(?P<password>.{7,50})/(?P<newsletter>\d)'] = array(
    array( array( $this, 'settings_update'), WP_JSON_Server::ALLMETHODS ),
);
```

and the part I need help with is the `(?P<password>.{7,50})`

Right now it accepts 7-50 characters for the password but I also want the update to work if there is NO password submitted. ie. "/dn/settings/update//1"

How can I do something like `.{0||7,50}` while not using `.{0, 50}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make your whole pattern optional:

```
$routes['/dn/settings/update/(?P<password>.{7,50})?/(?P<newsletter>\d)'] = array(
    array( array( $this, 'settings_update'), WP_JSON_Server::ALLMETHODS ),
);
```